# Scheme box and pointer cyclic list

Tags: scheme

I am trying to understand what is happening when writing this code by drawing it with the box and pointer method but cant quite get it. Anybody that could help?

```
(define bar (list 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e))
(set-cdr! (cdddr bar) (cdr bar))
```

My idea:

[image]

Also I don't know how to start to draw a diagram for the code under, I cant see where the points and boxes for (car) need to be.

```
(define bah (list 'bring 'a 'towel))
(set-car! bah (cdr bah))
```

Comment: It's a circular list. Please post your own box and pointer diagram, so we can help you better ;)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez added :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the initial situation:

[image]

And this is the final situation:

[image]

If you try to print `bah`, it is printed as a three element list, whose first element is a two element list:

```
((a towel) a towel)
```

But in fact the two structures are shared, so that, for instance, if you do:

```
(set-car! (cddr bah) 'handkerchief)
```

`bah` will be printed as:

```
((a handkerchief) a handkerchief)
```